# Disabling Mission Control (OR making plist changes take effect immediately)

Tags: macos, mission-control, plist

EDIT: I have just realized that what I'm talking about isn't a default feature in Lion. I probably added the commands via an article like [this](http://gigaom.com/apple/make-lions-mission-control-behave-more-like-spaces/) (scroll down to "Gestures and keyboard shortcuts"). So this question is more about how to make plist changes take effect immediately from Terminal.

I have spent about 4 hours looking for and developing a solution for a quick way to disable / enable Mission Control. My present line of thinking is:

I can disable the shortcuts to Mission Control, which would give me the same effect.

Oh look, I can disable the shortcuts via `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`! Let's see how I can modify that...

Darn it, the `defaults` command doesn't let me go deep enough into the sub-dictionaries to do what I want. But wait, I found `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`! Now to write a script...

The [script](https://gist.github.com/1810634) works (it changes the settings in the .plist file), but the changes aren't taking effect.

My questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. What command can I add to my script to make my changes take effect immediately? You can see I have `killall Dock` in the script, and I've tried `killall Finder` and `killall SystemUIServer`, but none of those seem to work.

Hopefully this is the best place to ask this... I know this is OS-X-specific, but it's also highly technical.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't really a better way to force a process to reload its preferences other than killing it.  Be careful: a process may flush its preferences when it is killed, so your change may get overwritten.